# Using Fieldgroups with Entity Registration Module

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using the [Entity Registration](http://drupal.org/project/registration) module to create event signup forms.  I've got my first event registration form up and running and now want to group some of the fields into fieldsets.

I have the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module installed, and have used it to group my fields into fieldsets (via Manage Display):

[image]

The effect I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

However the fieldsets are not showing on the registration form or in the markup:

[image]

According to Field Group module, it should work with any entity:

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together.  **All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together**.

I've searched the Entity Registration issue queue, but can't find anything relating to this.  Has anyone managed to get fieldsets working with Entity Registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was missing a step, I didn't realise that you had to create your field groups in Manage Display AND Manage Fields.  Seems a bit strange having to re-create the same field groups twice, but doing that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add corresponding group to add steps in it. See image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nikhil.  I tried your suggestion but I still don't see any fieldsets on the registration form.  I've updated my question with the result I want to achieve, I don't need a multi step form, only fieldsets but it's not working for some reason.